# Export `css` from Styled components macro are not found

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, npm-package

I have a components library made with styled components and published on npm. To have better class names, I'm using `babel-plugin-styled-components`, which works well if I'm working locally. If I install the npm package on another project, I get this error: `export 'css' (imported as 'css') was not found in 'styled-components/macro' (possible exports: default)`. Does anyone have an idea why and how I could fix it?

This is my babel config:

.babelrc:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        [
            "babel-plugin-styled-components",
            {
                "fileName": false,
                "pure": true,
                "meaninglessFileNames": [
                    "index",
                    "styles"
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

babel-plugin-macros.config.js

```
const config = {
    fileName: false,
    displayName: true,
    meaninglessFileNames: ["index", "styles"],
}

module.exports = { styledComponents: config }
```

Thanks for your answers!